# Winform ui will not update unless restarted

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having trouble updating the information passed through my program. I am using the following code to collect and set data. Behind the scenes it updates to the xml file correctly. I am only able to see the form ui update when the program is restarted. I would like for the controls of my program to be updated and shown once the backgroundworker is completed,update both the listbox with new data, and read in from the xml file, as well as the stack. Thank you in advance. I hope my question is not too confusing.

```
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load("Settings.xml");
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("Settings.xml");
    public static Stack list = new Stack();

public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ReadXml();
            reader.Close();
 foreach (string items in list)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(items);

            }
    }
public void WriteToXML()
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Settings.xml", settings))
            {

                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Folder_Settings");

                if (DocumentsCheckbox.Checked == true)
                {
                    writer.WriteElementString("Documents", "Checked");
                }
                else if (DocumentsCheckbox.Checked == false)
                {
                    writer.WriteElementString("Documents", "Not Checked");
                }

                if (PicturesCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    writer.WriteElementString("Pictures", "Checked");
                }
                else if (PicturesCheckBox.Checked == false)
                {
                    writer.WriteElementString("Pictures", "Not Checked");
                }

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();

                writer.Close();
            }
        }

 public void ReadXml()
        {

            XmlNodeType type;

            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    type = reader.NodeType;

                    if (reader.Name == "Documents")
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        if (reader.Value == "Checked")
                        {
                            DocumentsCheckbox.Checked = true;

                            list.Push(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));

                        }
                        else if (reader.Value == "Not Checked")
                        {
                            DocumentsCheckbox.Checked = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (reader.Name == "Pictures")
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        if (reader.Value == "Checked")
                        {

                            PicturesCheckBox.Checked = true;
                            list.Push(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures));

                        }
                        else if (reader.Value == "Not Checked")
                        {
                            PicturesCheckBox.Checked = false;
                        }
                    }
        }
         }


private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WriteToXML();
        ReadXml();
            updateApplication.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

private void updateApplication_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        { 

            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                updateApplication.ReportProgress(i);

            }


        }


        private void updateApplication_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            ApplyProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }


        private void updateApplication_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReadXml();
            Refresh();
            Application.DoEvents();
            //this does not do what i want it too.

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The XmlTextReader class is a forward only reader.  Once you have read to the end of the file Read() will return false.  So your second call to ReadXml() does nothing.

Instead create a new XmlTextReader object in ReadXml and use that.  There is no need for the reader to be at the class level.  This will ensure that you are always reading the current file from disk from the start.  Also note that XmlTextReader implements IDisposable so it should be wrapped in a using statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have 1 fundamental issue in the way you have declared your XmlTextReader object. You see you're calling the [Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.close(v=vs.110).aspx) in your MainForm() which clears all the resources of the object, **reader**, once the Form is loaded and thereby you can't use it further. Therefore, you have to re-start the program to see the changes.

I suggest, just like your **WriteToXML()**, declare the **XmlTextReader** inside your **ReadXml()**. Don't forget to move the call to the **close()** also into the ReadXml() as it's important to release the resources once you're done using it.

Alternatively, you can also declare the XmlTextReader in a using block inside the ReadXml(). So you don't have to worry about the **Close()**.